# Scheduled Task requiring "Highest Privileges" suddenly?

Tags: scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2

I've scheduled 5 tasks on a Windows Server 2008 under a local administrator windows account. Each tasks starts a .NET application (console application).

After severals months of running as scheduled, the tasks have stopped running as scheduled all a sudden and now requires that I check "Run with Highest Privileges".

Everything runs fine after I make the modification; no binaries replaced, no known account modification have been made or notified to me.

The running windows local account is still a member of "Administrators" as I set it up months ago.

What could have been the reason requiring "Highest Privileges" all of sudden? Does it have to do with how UAC are managed on WinServer2008?

Thanks again for your reply,

Comment: Perhaps try a new local admin account?  That might narrow it down to a problem with the account.

Comment: Thanks, I've 250+ production environment where application is committed with a standard installation procedure. This issue has been encountered 10 times after 1 year+ on the overall number of environment. Local windows admin account bears standards information and creation procedure, still, WIndow Server 2008 will stop scheduling task on some of them.

Comment: I think it more likely to be triggered by something someone did while logged on interactively than to be a spontaneous failure, though it's hard to guess without knowing more about what the console application does.

Comment: 2 of the console applications are .NET 4.0 (C#) apps which read/write some data from a local SQL Server 2008 instance and serialize this data into json file within a .zip package file. 3 others apps are also  .NET 4.0 (C#) apps which uses POP3/SMTP client to receive/send zip packages file from/to a local MS Exchange server.  MS Exchange server is hosted on a Active directory, mail server authentication is set to NTLM with restriction/rule taking into account the local windows account used to install/run the scheduled task. Hope this helps, the original issues seems somehow erratic to me. Thx,